# Is it normal that the installation takes more than 2 hours?

Tags: system-installation, 11.10

I'm new to Ubuntu and I'm trying to install it on my boyfriend's laptop. But it's been more than two hours since I've started the installation and now I'm stuck on *"Configuration du système de destination"* (don't know what it is in english... I'm installing the french version).

What can I do? Should I reboot the computer?

Answer (score 4):

When I recently installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my desktop, it took a long time too because I had selected to download and install updates during initial install.  For what it's worth, my install was 3+ hours long and I have a fairly quick cable modem connection.

> Should I reboot the computer?

No, just let it sit for a while and it should come back.

If you're interested, you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> to get to a text console and `tail` the install log to see if it is stuck at some step.

If it does get powered off, you should be able to re-start the installation and it should be fine.  If you do restart, don't select the updates option - it should go much faster since it will only use the DVD install media files.

Comment: i suggest this is the solution (updates), since i was able to install from an usb stick on a very outdated netbook (1gb ram, 900 mhz processor) without the update option in less then half an hour.

Answer (score 1):

My Acer Aspire took 6 hours the first time (both my desktop and netbook) but my HP laptop only took an hour. I've found (my opinion) that the fastest and most stable way to install 11.10 is to install without an Internet connection and then run the update manager afterwards. So far this has been the only way to get a stable installation on my particular system.

Comment: @Rob.. i agree..my installs never take more than 20 min from disk but once i tried downloading updates during the process and it took forever... update AFTER installing from iso

Answer (score 1):

**TIMING issue resolution for complete install and first run of Ubuntu 11.10**

Time to completion: Live media - around 2 hours and WEB@DSL - around 1.25 hours.

**Live Media**

Not longer than 1.5 hours. If your install goes past this time, consider the following:

- Disc Media is bad. Burn a fresh copy after downloading ISO of the latest stable version from ubuntu.com.
- *Hardware issue:*
  Too little RAM, Overheating CPU, HDD < 2 GB [really?], busted USB, or BUSTED media read device. Diag, Fix or Replace the busted module, [or call your PC TECH if you don't feel you can fix the problem safely on your own]

---

**WUBI**

If you experience a freeze or real slow install time > 1 hour, cancel install.

- Check your network, confirm the computer you're prepping for WUBI is attached to the network.

Reboot computer, start your Windows task manager, click on the networking tab, run WUBI again [uninstall will happen then you can re choose your install config] on 54 MBPS with Network usage no less than 3% total time to first run will be 1 hour.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the installation media can be a good idea, or download it with Transmission bit torrent as it checks the the iso file (unlike http or ftp that can fail without any feedback!)

The other problem is if you use the option to download updates while installing. That can be a very bad idea as I can testify:

I have tried to install Xubuntu several times and it took an all night doing nothing apparently but blinking the disk light. This was on a slow Toshiba NB305 with only 1GB of RAM. Normally when I install Linux on more able machines it takes about 15 to 30 minutes to install even activating the updates during install.

I started to install the latest regular release, 17.10.1, Artful Aardvark, and the live usb disk started quickly enough. Then I started installation on hard disk. I was selecting Transfer updates, and Install Third Party Software, but could never end the installation. I also tried latest Linux Mint with similar problem.

This last time I tried to install Xubuntu but not selecting to transfer updates. After that box, it took 4 minutes to continue (just the hour glass and no information of what is going wrong). I checked memory usage and it was still high at 650MB (and went up to 860MB during installation). Eventually I got to choose the rest of the options and from then on it was quick.

As always when reinstalling (and even when installing fresh) I avoided the useless option of deleting the disk and so I configured mount points properly myself. All went as normal.

Total install time went down from 10 hours and no result to 1 hour and success! After install, I went to the command line and typed:

```
sudo su
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

That took another 30 minutes.

Conclusion: Avoid the use of the update option. It doesn't work properly because after a fresh install with updates the system must be updated anyway!

This time it took minutes to install plus minutes to update after installation.